# xcode show the implementation of custom framework when there is an error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks

is xcode suppose to show the implementation of custom framework when there is an error?

i have made a custom framework, and it's works fine,
it's look like this:
[image]

in my viewcontroller i have a button action, that call a method in the framework

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
       dview.exchangeSubviewAtIndex(0, withSubviewAtIndex: 2, animated: true)
    }
```

since i have only 3 subviews the button action will work,
however, if i do this:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
       dview.exchangeSubviewAtIndex(0, withSubviewAtIndex: 20, animated: true)
    }
```

it's will crash, and it's ok, since i pass a value that does'nt exist in the array, but i didn't expected xcode to show the implementation of the framework,
instead xcode takes me to the line of code in the implementation :

[image]

basically, i don't want it to show the implementation of code in the framework..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your framework contains debug information which includes file locations.

Since you are using the same machine, `lldb` debugger is able to locate the source code where your app crashed.

You can move the Framework's Xcode project to different location on your Mac to see the difference.

Comment: Works great now,Thank you !